High F1 score, precision and recall on training, validation set and test set on all models
I am working on a dataset about emissions from Kaggle. There are some features such as fuel consumption, fuel, etc. I tried to make a classification task from this dataset by defining emissions above 255 as unacceptable (1) and under that acceptable (0). The data is imbalanced, the acceptable class has 13269 data and the unacceptable class has 9287 data. I am trying to use different classification models such as the Random forest classifier, decision tree classifier, and logistic regression and all of these models achieve an f1 score of near 1 on the training set, validation set and even test set which seems weird. The data has no missing or null values and is normalized by the standard scaler before feeding it into models.
enter image description hereenter image description here
My first assumption was data leakage when all models were performing like this. I checked multiple times the codes and even checked the datasets with function and there are no duplicate rows between the training set and test set. I tried using all features and then some features that random forest found most relative such as "COMB (L/100 km)", "COMB (mpg)", "FUEL CONSUMPTION", "HWY (L/100 km)", "CYLINDERS", "ENGINE SIZE" and play with them a little bit, but still got high scores on all precision, recall and f1. I make the dataset balanced by removing some data from the larger class by chance. I made my models using grid search, so I tried to make the model more complex and simple by defining different parameter grids and also by defining manually. I also checked the precision and recall by threshold.
enter image description here
enter image description here

"I tried to make a classification task from this dataset by defining emissions above 160 as unacceptable (1) and under that acceptable (0). The data is imbalanced, the acceptable class has 13269 data and the unacceptable class has 9287 data." I tried the same thing, by creating a new column called acceptable with the code df['acceptable'] = (df['emissions'] < 160).astype('float'). This gets a very different result: 926 acceptable and 21630 unacceptable. Can you clarify how you got these numbers?

I think it makes sense that you'd be able to get scores this high on this dataset. Gasoline is 90% carbon. The car mostly expels all carbon into the atmosphere. So fuel efficiency ("COMB (L/100 km)") will correlate very very strongly with CO2 emissions.

@Nick ODell Sorry that was a mistake in explaining the problem, I first split the data from 0 to 160, 160 to 255 and 255 to infinity as low, medium and high. But after seeing that the low class is 926 I change it to 0 to 255 as acceptable and above that as unacceptable. I will try other features then without "COMB (L/100 km)" to see if the model's performance decreases. Thanks for your explanation.

@user:530160 Sorry that was a mistake in explaining the problem, I first split the data from 0 to 160, 160 to 255 and 255 to infinity as low, medium and high. But after seeing that the low class is 926 I change it to 0 to 255 as acceptable and above that as unacceptable. I will try other features then without "COMB (L/100 km)" to see if the model's performance decreases. Thanks for your explanation
